# Mongo update 'in-place' only $inc?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

MongoDB post about update 'in-place': http://blog.mongodb.org/post/248614779/fast-updates-with-mongodb-update-in-place

But it is only $inc?

Comment: The question is that only $inc 'in-place' or not only $inc?

Comment: There are a whole bunch, $set is one for example

Comment: In fact I believe all of the main update operators: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/#fields are in place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any and all updates which modify the documents *without growing its size* will be in place.

The simplest example of it is `$inc` because it doesn't change the type of the first and incrementing a number does not require more storage space.  But doing a `$set` without increasing the storage the value needs would also be "in place".

Comment: this answer applies to MMAPV1 storage engine only, and not to WiredTiger.